# Is it ok to invalidate or delete low level cache in models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have implemented a low level caching in a service. So I need to invalidate it once the active record model created, update or destroy. At first, I did invalidating on controller side. It works, but my colleague suggested to put it on model callbacks instead and it still works.

So my question are:

1. Is it ok to invalidate it on the model section rather that controller?
2. Is there any cons for that?

Thanks in advance for your answer. Happy coding! ;)

Comment: Yes, it is always good practice to invalidate cache in your model callback and that can be reuse from other places too.

Comment: What are you caching and how does it relate to the model or controller?

Comment: @LHH callbacks are at best a convenient solution - I would hardly say that its a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to invalidate it on the model section rather that controller?

Well the Rails police aren't going to come and stop you.

The advantage of model callbacks is that they in theory are always fired without you having to lift a finger. And thats really where it ends.

The cons is that they don't have any awareness at all of the context besides the lifecycle of the model and its easy to end up with hacky solutions to suppress the callbacks.

Model callbacks also fall short when there is more then one model involved in the picture. Should the responsibity in  be of Model A or Model B? Both? Neither?

Also one question thats should be asked is if you really should be burdoning your models with yet another responsibility? In Rails models are already doing persistence, database queries, typecasting, validations, serialization, interacting with I18n, ActiveStorage, polymorphic routing, etc. In other frameworks you would spread these tasks over database repositories, form objects and more.

And another aspect thats often missed is that not everything in a Rails app actually belongs in M,V, or C. There are other patterns such as the [repository pattern](https://engineering.solarisbank.com/the-repository-pattern-in-ruby-with-the-active-record-library-f0445fa282c) that can be used if you have a messy/expensive query that needs to be encapsulated.

Comment: The question implies this is caching calls to a service, which suggests a [service object](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial).

Comment: @Schwern thats also a very good alternative.